# android facebook sdk set "likes"

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I need to set a "like" to a certain facebook account from within my android application. I am using an official facebook-android-sdk. I created an activity that extends `com.facebook.FacebookActivity`, put `openSession()` into `onCreate()`.

Here is a callback:

```
@Override
protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        // I want to "like" a certain facebook account.
        // What code should I write here?
    }
}
```

Having searched docs, I found this:

`setLikes(JSONObject)` - Method in interface `com.facebook.OpenGraphAction`

Sets the 'likes' that have been performed on this action.

But I'm not sure that this is exactly what I need. Also it is unclear for me how do I obtain `com.facebook.OpenGraphAction` and what should `JSONObject` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that it's not possible to like a page. It seems to be possible to like a post, but not a page. So the only way here is to bring user to the Facebook page where he is supposed to press "like it" and, after he pressed "back" button, check if he liked us actually.